# Is there a good rule for using 'const' in classes and operator overloads in C++?

Tags: c++, constants, copy-constructor

I have a piece of code like this:

```
class EducationalCentre
{
    string _centreName;
    vector<Course> _courses;    // courses offered by the Centre
    Collection<Course*, Student*, 150> _applicants;

public:
    EducationalCentre(string name="<name>")
    {
        _centreName = name;
    }

    EducationalCentre(const EducationalCentre& obj) 
        :_courses(obj._courses), _applicants(obj._applicants) 
    {
        _centreName = obj._centreName;
    }
};
```

Now, in this part `_applicants(obj._applicants)` copy construction header, there's a squiggly red line around `(obj`, hovering it the error says something about type incompatibility (`const` being mentioned).

Since I don't want to change anything at this stage (this is a part of exam test) - I would like to know why is that happening.

I tried removing the `const` from `EducationalCentre(const EducationalCentre& obj)` and that indeed solves the problem but.. As I said, I would rather learn about what causes this instead of removing it.

Comment: What does `Collection`'s copy constructor look like?  Also if you compile what is the actual error message you get?

Comment: `Collection` copy ctor taking a non-const argument would explain this behavior. Copy ctor should take a const argument.

Comment: Get away from "squiggly red lines". Your code must pass the compiler, not the IDE!

Comment: Collection is probably missing a the constructor, or declaring it without const

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic Yeah, `Collection` doesn't have `const` there. That is because whenever I use it, I'm having issues (this is a generic type class). Any advice on that, ie. using `const` in generic classes?

Comment: Can you explain issues?  A copy constructor should almost always take its parameter by `const &`

Comment: Yes: use `const` whenever you can :) The class being generic should not have anything to do with copy ctor taking const reference. Probably some of methods you use in copy ctor on your argument is non-const and that is why you can't make argument const.

Comment: I don't see any MS-specific stuff here, just plain C++. Or is it ? I'd suggest removing the [tag:visual-c++] tag.

Comment: @NathanOliver In particular, I remember using it in `operator<<` of a generic class always gives me headache so I'm avoiding it in generic classes altogether. However, I will try not to do so anymore because I'm suspecting that creates other issues down the road.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rule for using `const` is to use it whenever you can :)

Of course, like with all best practices there are exceptions, but in general you should always strive to make non-static methods `const` if they don't mutate the state of the object.

The reason for the problem you get is that `Collection` copy constructor takes a non-const reference to the instance it uses as a source object.

Copy constructor can take const or non-const reference as its argument but, IMO, non-const should only be used when you have no choice, which is rarely. Creating an object based on another object should not change the source object, thus it should be marked as `const`.

As I noted in the comment, the class being generic has nothing to do with copy ctor taking const reference. Indeed, if you take a look at e.g. `std::vector` you will see that it has a copy constructor which takes a const reference. Probably some of methods you use in `Collection` copy constructor on your argument is non-const and that is why you can't make argument const. The solution is to make the offending method const, too.

This brings us to an important point: `const`ness is viral. If you mark a method const, all other method it calls on itself must also be const. Same for calling methods on const objects - you can only call const methods. If you don't do it from the beginning, you may end up in situation where making one method const results in changing a whole chain of other methods, so it is easier to give up.

Why constness is good: most bugs are caused by mutating application state in unexpected ways - just ask functional programming fans who rave about immutability :). A const method can't change the state of the object, so it eliminates the possibility of unexpected changes: e.g. if an exception is thrown in the middle of a const method, you can be sure that the object is not in some half-modified state which invalidates class invariants.

Now, C++ is not only an object oriented language, so you can change the application state in other ways, and also you can misuse `mutable` and `const_cast` to trick the compiler, but using `const` helps a lot in writing correct software and lowering the debugging efforts.